# Dynamic multi-thread server problem

Tags: c++, multithreading, dynamic, vector

```
 while(true)
        {
        Klient temp;
        SOCKET client = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&ich,&sin_size);
        if (client!= INVALID_SOCKET)
                        {
                                int ID = wszyscy.size(); //wszyscy is a vector of Klient structure; ID increments like: 0,1,2,3 etc
                                memset(&temp,0,sizeof(Klient)); //zero structure
                                temp.Gniazdo = client; //fill temporary structure
                                temp.Identyfikator = ID;
                                temp.Nick = "";
                                temp.Watek = NULL;
                                wszyscy.push_back(temp);//Adding
                                std::cout << ID << std::endl; //Showing ID for test
                                std::cout << inet_ntoa(ich.sin_addr) << std::endl;//IP 
                                wszyscy[ID].Watek = CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) Watek,&wszyscy[ID], 0 ,NULL);//Creating thread
        }
    }
```

Thread:

```
DWORD Watek(LPVOID Dane)
{
        const char* tekst_serwera = "Halo, tu server :D\n\0";
        Klient *temp = (Klient*) Dane;
        send(temp->Gniazdo,tekst_serwera,strlen(tekst_serwera),0);
        std::cout << "Podlaczyl sie klient o ID: " << temp->Identyfikator << std::endl;
        char bufor[500];
        while(true)
        {
                memset(bufor,0,500);
                recv(temp->Gniazdo,bufor,500,0);
                std::cout << bufor;
        }
}
```

The problem is when I launch 2 or more clients, server send to them as it suppose to welcome messages(tekst_servera) but when I write something on client who has been launched as second and then I try to write something on client who has been launched as first server is getting 80%CPU usage and does not receive data, only the first one(It happens only on client who has been launched as first) When I did temp.watek = CreateThread and then push_back server was still not responding to client number 1 messages but was not lagging like hell.

Any help appreciated

Comment: The while(true) in the Thread will eat a lot of CPU if the recv() is not blocking.

Comment: It's not the problem because if I launch like 50 clients and write only on 2-50, not on the first one then everything is allright.When I did the same server but on static 20 limited array everything worked fine.

Comment: Show us the code for `Klient`.

Comment: OK... maybe you should show the client too? 

By the way, it might be easier to understand your code if the variables and messages are in English... (I do that even though I'm Swedish... :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to [winsock documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (msdn.microsoft.com), the recv function will return one of the following values:

- positive: The number of bytes received;
- zero: connection was closed;
- negative: an error has occurred.

I strongly suggest checking the return value of `recv()`, and terminating the loop when necessary, because in both the zero and negative cases, you'll be stuck in a loop, calling recv() which returns without blocking immediately. This would show up as high CPU usage and non-responsive server threads.

In any case, throwing away the return value from a function you call is bad form, and should only be done in exceptional situations.